# How to Loop this following script in R instead of Repeating the same exact steps all the time for each file

Tags: r, loops, export-to-csv

I am new to R. I am working on cmip6 models. I have over 200 plus .nc files. I can run the script for individual files and get the output i need but having hard time looping the script. Can you guys help me out. It will save me alot of my time. Thank you in advance.

```
   setwd("D:\\data")
library (raster)  ## load required library
library(sp)    ## load library
library(ncdf4)


station.data = read.csv(file.choose(), sep = ",", header =T) ## import station data.file
lon.lat = station.data[,c(2,3)] ## extract data of all stations in station file for which point values are to be extractd
lon.lat = SpatialPoints(lon.lat) ## lon.lat for further use
lon.lat
robject = brick(file.choose(), varname = "pr")## import raster netcdf file from which point values are to be extractd
dim(robject) ## check the dimensions of project
vall = extract(robject , lon.lat, method = "simple" ) ## extract values 
vall = t(vall)
write.csv(vall, file = "earthvegbil.csv", fileEncoding = "macroman") ## save output csv file containing extracted point values .
```

Comment: Set working directory to the folder containing the files in question with setwd("dir"), use the function list.files with argument pattern equal "*.extension", where extension is whatever extension your files have. Use a for loop to go through every file and run your code for every file. It is hard to help when you do not provide a reproducible example nor the exact termination of the files in question. In general, avoid using file.choose(), since it is irreproducible.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Ventrilocus . So my input files are in .nc format and its name starts with "pr" so its easy to list/choose them with list.files(pattern="pr") . Station file is constant so i have replaced it with station.csv instead of file.choose . Now I want is a separate output file in a .csv format for each of my input file whose name preferably would be same as the input files. The above script does the job well , just gotta loop it T*T . I am Noob af at programming, started learning it recently as i need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in an `lapply` and loop over the *indeces* of your files. The latter is useful to get nice numerical suffixes in `write.csv`.

```
setwd("D:\\data")
files <- list.files(pattern=".csv$") 
bricks <- list.files(pattern=".pr$") 

stopifnot(length(files) == length(bricks))  ## check for equal length of both vectors

mapply(seq_along(files), \(x) {
  station.data <- read.csv(files[[x]], sep=", ", header=T) ## import station data.file
  lon.lat <- station.data[, c(2, 3)] ## extract data of all stations in station file for which point values are to be extractd
  lon.lat <- SpatialPoints(lon.lat) ## lon.lat for further use
  robject <- brick(bricks[[x]], varname="pr")## import raster netcdf file from which point values are to be extractd
  vall <- extract(robject , lon.lat, method="simple" ) ## extract values 
  vall <- t(vall)
  write.csv(vall, file=sprintf('./out/earthvegbil_%03d.csv', x), fileEncoding="macroman") ## save output csv file containing extracted point values .
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf . I feel like my query was not clear enough .So my input files are in .nc format and its name starts with "pr" so its easy to list/choose them with list.files(pattern="pr") . Station file is constant so i have replaced it with station.csv instead of file.choose . Now I want is a separate output file in a .csv format for each of my input file whose name preferably would be same as the input files. The above script(that I shared) does the job well , just gotta loop it T*T . I am Noob af at programming, started learning it recently as i need it

Comment: @HarithS Good you understand how to search for patterns, just add `"$"` to denote the string end after the pattern. I changed the code slightly so you use `list.files` two times, once for .csv, once for .pr. They get sorted alphabetically each. Since they should be of  of equal length, it's sufficient to loop over `seq_along(files)` to get the indices.

Comment: thank you so much for the help , now its working like butter <3 . and made me understand how looping works *^*